# model management in MVC

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, architecture

I'm searching for a best practice for making a model in MVC.
I'm making a socket server with concurrent users.
As I understand, a model in MVC has included business logic so that if I get a model from a data access or maybe db SAO.

How can this model object be updated when someone else has changed an attribute in the DB ?

The first solution I can think of is to always get an attribute of model by accessing it from the database.
The second one is to make a model pool and modify the reference.

Any suggestion??

Comment: Your database is the single point of truth. When you need data, get it from the database. That's what it's for.

Comment: @JBNizet So in model there will have nothing in struct but getting method from db?

Comment: any suggestion, It's a realtime game with heavy data read write how should I have to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have just one server and just one process, you could cache your model (static variables or similiar) and you will just have one model in memory that mirrors the database. But this would scale bad (or better won't scale at all). So depending on how much latency you could tolerate, you could have several servers and processes which have their own caches, updating from database in regular intervals. This could of course mean data corruption. Another way will be that if one server changes an entity it informs all other servers via sockets to invalidate that entity in their caches. A midway would be that all servers cache in memory, but every time an object is requested, only the timestamp (or version) is pulled from the database to decide wether the cache is up to date.